# Menu scaling in browser

Tags: html, css

While scaling down in browser menu has broken - flows on next line. What is wrong in code? Div width changing while scaling though it hardcoded 198px.
Without borders all is ok, but I have to use borders.

```css
#horizontal-multilevel-menu {
  border-right: 1px solid #769510;
  border-left: 1px solid #cde67b;
}
#horizontal-multilevel-menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #a0bf38;
  min-height: 52px;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 1000px;
}
#horizontal-multilevel-menu a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 40px !important;
}
#horizontal-multilevel-menu div {
  float: left;
  border-left: 1px solid #769510;
  border-right: 1px solid #cde67b;
  width: 198px;
}
```

```html
<div id="horizontal-multilevel-menu">
  <div><a href="/1/" class="root-item">1</a>
  </div>
  <div><a href="/2/" class="root-item">2</a>
  </div>
  <div><a href="/3/" class="root-item">3</a>
  </div>
  <div><a href="/4/" class="root-item">4</a>
  </div>
  <div><a href="/5/" class="root-item">5</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use width in % for child div and with less as border will also take width so..ex if you are taking 1000px then in 5 div use 19% width and it will be ok..

Comment: Leo, thanks for reply. I usy "double" borders between divs, and "single" on div#horizontal-multilevel-menu, so menu with 19% doesnt flow on next line now, but still wrong with last border (there is space between last div and last border of div#horizontal-multilevel-menu).

Comment: css selector..can you please tell me what you want exactly so i can help you in better way..any example..

Comment: Does it? Its all on one line here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you need `box-sizing` to correct this issue.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#horizontal-multilevel-menu {
  border-right: 1px solid #769510;
  border-left: 1px solid #cde67b;
}
#horizontal-multilevel-menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #a0bf38;
  min-height: 52px;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 1000px;
}
#horizontal-multilevel-menu a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 40px !important;
}
#horizontal-multilevel-menu div {
  float: left;
  border-left: 1px solid #769510;
  border-right: 1px solid #cde67b;
  width: 199px;
}
```

```html
<div id="horizontal-multilevel-menu">
  <div><a href="/1/" class="root-item">1</a>
  </div>
  <div><a href="/2/" class="root-item">2</a>
  </div>
  <div><a href="/3/" class="root-item">3</a>
  </div>
  <div><a href="/4/" class="root-item">4</a>
  </div>
  <div><a href="/5/" class="root-item">5</a>
  </div>
</div>
```